# Question about proof with doubly stochastic matrix. Why do we need the uniqueness of $\pi_j?$

Tags: markov-chains

> A stochastic matrix is called doubly stochastic if its rows and
>   columns sum to 1. Show that a Markov chain whose transition matrix is
>   doubly stochastic  has a stationary distribution, which is uniform on
>   the statespace.

I'm trying to under stand the [related problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1361358/doubly-stochastic-matrix-proof) but I don't understand how the uniqueness theorem comes in in the first row of the accepted answer, shouldm't it be $\pi_i$? What do those sums even mean? They don't have any upper bound but i suppose the upper bound should be the upper bound of the statespace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're using the uniqueness theorem so that, when they show that the uniform distribution is a valid stationary distribution for the doubly stochastic transition matrix, it must be ***the*** stationary distribution.

The uniqueness of the stationary distribution comes directly out of the irreducibility of $P$ + aperiodicity of $P$ + finite state space of the system, and the sums are just matrix multiplications over the state space (from $i=0$ to $M$).